# Oracle Database 19c Not available tnsnames.ora file

Tags: oracle, centos7, oracle19c

I am working with `Oracle 19c` in `Centos`. After Oracle installation, not available **tnsnames.ora** file.but the **listener.ora** file is available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should reside in your `oracle_home\network\admin` directory.

If not, create one yourself. Download sample file (from e.g. [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-network-configuration#TNSNames)) and adjust it so that it reflects your environment.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try this.

Comment: Or use 'netca' to create and maintain it.  As you can see, it does not come by default.